# Ajax returning the same last value not the updated value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have to update my database using the modal pop up.so my main page php is

Main.php

```
<a href='javascript:void(0):' data-id={$row['customer_id']} class='btn small bg-blue-alt tooltip-button modal-customeredit' data-placement='top' title='Edit'><i class='glyph-icon icon-edit' ></i>

</a>
```

it will open a jquery pop up,i get the id as jquery variable and send it to php via ajax 
using this code.

jquery page

```
$( ".modal-customeredit" ).click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myGroupId = $(this).attr('data-id'); // data-id

    $.post("sample.php",
           {
               name:myGroupId,
               async: false           
           },
           function(data,status){
               alert(status)
           });
    $( "#modal-customeredit" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        minWidth: 700,
        minHeight: 200,
        dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
        show: "fadeIn"
    });

    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('bg-black opacity-60');
});
```

sample.php will get the id and set session

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {

        $value = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION["user_id"]=$value;
        print_r ($value);
    }
?>
```

so in the modal form php will be.

```
</div>
<!-- Customer Edit -->

<div class="hide" id="modal-customeredit" title="Edit Customer">
    <div class="mrg25T">
    <!--<h3>new Customer Info</h3>
    <p class="font-gray-dark"> Fides Admin rdfgdf colors & styles from both the default theme color schemes and the included core color helpers. </p>
    <div class="divider"></div>-->
    <?php

    $_SESSION["user_id"];
$id=  $_SESSION["user_id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_mast  where  customer_id=$id") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
if($result==false)
    {
        echo "error";
    }

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach($row AS $key => $value){
        $row[$key] = stripslashes($value);
    }

    echo '  <form id="edit-customer" action="customer_edit.php" class="col-md-12 center-margin" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-label col-md-3">
            <label for="name">
              Name:
              <span class="required">*</span>
                       </label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-input col-md-9">
            <input id="name" name="customer_name" placeholder="Name" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text" value="'.$row['customer_name'].'">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-label col-md-3">
            <label for="details">
              Details :
              <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-input col-md-9">
            <input id="details" placeholder="details" name="customer_details" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text" value="'.$row['customer_details'].'">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-label col-md-3">
            <label for="domain">
              Domain :
              <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-input col-md-9">
            <input id="domain" placeholder="Domain" name="domain" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text" value="'.$row['domain'].'">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-label col-md-3">
            <label for="vertical">
              Vertical :
              <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-input col-md-9">
            <input id="vertical" placeholder="Vertical" name="vertical" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text" value="'.$row['vertical'].'">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-label col-md-3">
            <label for="taxonomy">
              Taxonomy :
              <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-input col-md-9">
            <input id="taxonomy" placeholder="Taxonomy" name="taxonomy" data-required="true" class="parsley-validated" type="text" value="'.$row['taxonomy'].'">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
         <input type="submit" class="btn medium primary-bg" id="edit-customer-valid" name="submit" onclick="javascript:$(\'#edit-customer\').parsley( \'validate\' );" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
            </div>
          </div>';

}

?>
<?php } elseif ($pfile=="project.php") { ?>
```

so i get the id in main page pass it via jquery and send it to to another page via ajax,set a session and use it in modal form to update.But the problem is it will work only for the last id passed.Suppose i pass id from main page as 2 it will do update operation only for 2.even though i pass next time 3.So i have to refresh the page and to again pass the id 3.
I tried to give all the details.I know it may confusing,if you have any thoughts suggestion about this please help me.Thank you!

Comment: You calling session_start() on your main page?

Comment: You should pass a random variable or time with group id as data.

Comment: @johsua yes you are right.@amit can you be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your `modal page` using `ajax`, otherwise it will load the same `session userid` every time try to move your modal box html in other page like `modal-user.php` and use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) like,

```
$( "#modal-customeredit" )
     .load('modal-user.php') // load new session user details
                         // also use session_start() before using session user id
     .dialog({
        modal: true,
        minWidth: 700,
        minHeight: 200,
        dialogClass: "modal-dialog",
        show: "fadeIn"
     });
```

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding can you be more clear.Thank you in advance

Comment: In your code user-details loaded once and if modal box opens then it will show the previously loaded user details in modal box, so after updating `$_SESSION['user_id']` you must update `modal-box` html, it can be done by `reloading page` or by loading `modal-box` content every time by ajax, so I suggest to use second option in which I created a `modal-user.php` page to load modal-box content.

Comment: Thats a good idea but i am having confusion in implementing this.Is there i have to post that entire html form file to modal-user.php and call it in the jquery is that will work?

Comment: If i have keep modal in another page.ANd included in the main page.I get two forms at first time page loads once i click edit the modal will work fine.Before that i see modal form box at below the page.